# Conditional expectation and regular distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability, expectation

I have problem with proving the following fact:

Let $\mu$ be regular version of distribution of random variable $X$ with respect to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$. Let $Y$ be $\mathcal{B}$-measurable random variable. Prove that for any Borel function $\phi$ such that $\mathbb{E}|\phi (X,Y)|<\infty$, we have $$ \mathbb{E}(\phi(X,Y)|\mathcal{B})(\cdot) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, Y(\cdot)) \mu(dx, \cdot)\ \ \ \ \ \text{a.s.} $$
How does this equation look like for $X$ independent from $\mathcal{B}$?

I can see that function $\omega \mapsto \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, Y(\omega)) \mu(dx, \omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable, so it would be enough to prove that $$\forall_{B \in \mathcal{B}} \int \limits_{B} \mathbb{E}(\phi(X,Y)|\mathcal{B})(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{B} \phi(X(\omega),Y(\omega))dP(\omega) = \\ = \int \limits_{B}\left( \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, Y(\omega)) \mu(dx, \omega)\right)dP(\omega).$$

First equality is obvious from the definition of conditional expectation, but I have problem with second one.

I would apreciate every help.
Thanks!

Comment: How can you show that the integral gives a measurable function of w?

Answer (score 0):

The proof seems to go by complicating function $\phi$, starting from $\phi=I_{A\times B}$, for $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $Y$ is $\mathcal B$-measurable, it is:
$$P_{X\circ Y/\mathcal B}(\omega)(A\times B)=I_B(Y(\omega))P_{X/\mathcal B}(\omega)(A)$$
Hence:
$$\mathbb E[\phi(X,Y)\mid\mathcal B]=\int\phi(X,Y)dP_{\Omega/\mathcal B}=\int\phi(x,y)dP_{X\circ Y/\mathcal B}=\int\phi(x,Y)dP_{X/\mathcal B}$$